# date fiel type Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to display a choice date

```
->add('dueDate', 'date', array('format' => 'dd - MMMM - yyyy',
            'placeholder' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day')
```

but i get this formt of date

result of execution:

[image: result of execution]

Answer (score 2):

That date format doesn't look consistent with [PHP's date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Try this:

```
'format' => 'd - M - Y',
```

Comment: Symfony uses ICU Date Formats:  http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax ... his format is valid - despite its VERY un-PHP-ish appearance.

Comment: There might be something wrong in the view instead. Can we see that please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you linked, I think the problem is both in your template and your form builder.  If you define the 'widget' parameter like so:

```
->add('dueDate', 'date', array(
          'format' => 'dd - MMMM - yyyy',
          'placeholder' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
          'widget' => 'choice' ) );
```

Then you only need to make reference to the form_widget as a single entity in your temlate:

```
{{ form_widget( form.dueDate ) }}
```

And twig will automatically render 3 select fields.